# CMake SWIG dependency on headers of external project

Tags: cmake, dependencies, swig, external-project

I have a project "A" that depends on another project "B".

- ProjectB installs some headers, for example B1.h, B2.h.
- ProjectA tries to create a Python wrapper of B1.h and B2.h, using SWIG.

ProjectA uses :

- `ExternalProject_Add(ProjectB ...)` to compile and install ProjectB somwhere into the binary dir.
- `Swig_Add_Library(ProjectB ...)` to create the Python wrapper ; this command creates a target `_ProjectB`.

I want to be sure that B1.h, B2.h are installed *before* SWIG runs, thus I added the following command :
`add_dependencies(_ProjectB ProjectA)`

On Windows, this works fine.

However on Linux, the `add_dependencies` command is not taken into account, which gives :

```
.../ProjectA.i: 111: Error: Unable to find 'B1.h'
.../ProjectA.i: 112: Error: Unable to find 'B2.h'
```

I am sure that the include dir given to SWIG is correct: indeed, when I run `make` for the second time, this works because ProjectB was successfully installed by the first call to `make`.

I use CMake 3.13.5.

Any help would be great !

Comment: "I use CMake 3.13.5"... **why?** Use the latest version. [It's unbelievably easy to upgrade.](https://alexreinking.com/blog/how-to-use-cmake-without-the-agonizing-pain-part-1.html)

Comment: I use legacy code that is not compatible with recent CMake versions.
Anyway, I tried my specific issue with a recent CMake (3.19.4) and get the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround : on Linux, I use : `add_dependencies(ProjectB_swig_compilation ProjectA)`

However, the target `ProjectB_swig_compilation` does not exist on Windows (I don't understand why since I use the same version of CMake on both Linux and Windows).

Eventually, here is what I did in my CMakeLists.txt :

```
if (WIN32 AND NOT MINGW)
   add_dependencies(_ProjectB ProjectA)
else ()
   add_dependencies(ProjectB_swig_compilation ProjectA)
endif ()
```